# Yarn Resource manager-admin commands

Tags: admin, hadoop-yarn, rhel, rhel7, resourcemanager

I am new in yarn resource manager admin commands, I know how to check the status of the application with -appStates keyword. For example,

> yarn application -list -appStates FINISHED

will give all the finished jobs. We can do more with states like RUNNING, NEW, ALL, NEW_SAVING, SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, FINISHED, FAILED, KILLED.  But how to fetch the recent application submitted. Is there any keyword RECENT?
Something like this:

> yarn application -list -appStates RECENT

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want more fine-grained control of this, you should use the YARN Resource Manager REST APIs.  The [Cluster Applications API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_API) allows you to specify `startedTimeBegin` and `startedTimeEnd` which you can use to define how much time you mean by **RECENT**.  Just remember time is specified in **milliseconds** not seconds.

This simple script shows how you'd see jobs created in the last 5 minutes.

```
starttime=`date +"%s"`
let starttime=starttime-300
curl RM_URL/ws/v1/cluster/apps?startedTimeBegin=${starttime}000
```